# How to write selected text from firefox browser as a image

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox-addon, xul

The issue i am facing is:  suppose we select some text in the browser window. Then on mouse up I need to save that selected text as an image on the client's system.

I can write this selected text to a text file on local system through
JavaScript and XUL. But now i have to save this as a image?

Anybody have any JavaScript code or suggestion?

I have done this through firefox extension using XUL..only issue remaining is to save the text as image.

Comment: Are you talking about a Firefox add-on here, or are you intending to do this from an ordinary web page?

Answer (score 3):

You can do that using the [`<canvas>` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Canvas). It's an HTML tag but you can use it in XUL as well - just remember to specify the HTML namespace. If you specify that tag in your XUL document you do it like this:

```xml
<canvas xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" width="..." height="..."/>
```

Or, if you create it dynamically:

```js
var canvas = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml", "canvas");
```

You can then [draw text into the canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Drawing_text_using_a_canvas). And you can use `canvas.toDataURL()` to convert canvas contents to an image ([code snippet saving that image to a file](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Canvas#Saving_a_canvas_image_to_a_file)).

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
function getSelectedText()
{
    var t = '';
    if(window.getSelection)
        t = window.getSelection();
    else if(document.getSelection)
        t = document.getSelection();
    else if(document.selection)
        t = document.selection.createRange().text;

    return t;
}

$('.mySelectableItems').on('onmouseup', function(e)
{
    var text = getSelectedText();
    if(!text) return false;//stopping propagation!!

    var svg = $('<svg width="300" height="300"><text x="85" y="124">'+text+'</text></svg>');
});
```

After that put the svg into the web and in the img source put the svg url.

Via: [Here](http://blog.dholbert.org/2010/10/svg-as-image.html), [here](http://playground.html5rocks.com/#text_inside_svg) and also [here](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=31799&seqNum=2).